# “I never wanted you more" meaning?

Tags: sentence-meaning

In one episode of the show *Friends* season 2, Rachel said to Ross:

> I never wanted you more.

It confused me a lot. Does it mean I didn't want you any more or I wanted you most? How should I understand it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen the show, but I managed to find a copy of [the script](http://soncp.com/afs/217.html) online. The original line is actually:

> Rachel: I've never wanted you more.

The literal meaning of this line is "I really want you now." It leaves out a part that is being compared in the comparative structure. The sentence in its entirety would read:

> I've never wanted you more than (how much I want you) right now/this moment.

What is omitted is *than I want you now.* So the line in its literal meaning is an affirmative statement.

However, judging from the context, Rachel says that in a sarcastic tone. She actually means that she hates the sound Ross is making and finds it repellent.

Answer (score 3):

"Never" (not ever), means there was not an occurrence in the past.  So this is saying there was not a time in the past when I wanted you more than I do now.  This could be rephrased:

> I want you more now than I ever did before.